# Mocked MVC Session with its method seems not called when verify in assert

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit

I followed tutorial [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx) for mocking session in http context

I setup like:

```
var session = new Mock<SessionStateBase>();
session.Setup(s=>s.Clear());
```

and then add in context

```
context.Setup(c=>c.Session).Returns(session.Object);
```

And I use it to setup controller

```
var controller = new MyController();

context = MvcHelper.FakeHttpContext();
controller.SetFakeControllerContext(context);
controller.Index();

context.Verify(c=>c.Session.Clear(), Times.Once); // here's problem, UT says that is never called.
```

and my action looks like:

```
public ActionResult Index() {

   this.Session.Clear();

}
```

I debugged the test and I reach line where session clear method is called.

Why verify is failed ?

Comment: I would like to add that if that is the only line in the method, it has no logic, and therefore does not need to be tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Verify` failed because you are verifying the wrong mock.

The setup for `Clear` was on the `session`

```
session.Setup(s => s.Clear());
```

but you are calling the verify on `context`.

Update the test to verify on the `session`

```
session.Verify(_ => _.Clear(), Times.Once);
```

For what you have to work you would have had to setup the `context` like this

```
context.Setup(_ => _.Session.Clear());
```